# Only allow a certain range of numbers to be entered in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently in the process of making a 'popup menu' in VB.

One of the requirements is to only allow numbers between the ranges of 2.4 and 6 to be entered for the "height of the room" (see code below).

I am unsure on how to do this, and will be very thankful of any help. So far my code looks like this:

```
Sub WallPaint()
    num1 = Val(InputBox("Enter the height of the room"))
    num2 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the first wall"))
    num3 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the window"))

    ans = (num1 * num2) - num3

    MsgBox "The area of the room is " & ans
End Sub
```

Ok, thanks to Sujith I know now the layout. However I need to do this for a lot of queires. Is there a better way to lay out the data instead of this:

```
    Sub WallPaint()

num1 = Val(InputBox("Enter the height of the room"))    
If num1 > 2.4 And num1 < 6 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
num2 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the first wall"))    
If num2 > 1 And num2 < 25 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
num3 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the second wall"))    
If num3 > 1 And num2 < 25 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
num4 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the third wall"))    
If num4 > 1 And num2 < 25 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
num5 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the fourth wall"))    
If num5 > 1 And num2 < 25 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
num6 = Val(InputBox("Enter the height of the window"))    
If num6 > 0.9 And num6 < 1.5 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
num7 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the window"))    
If num7 > 0.9 And num7 < 2 Then    
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If    
ans = (num2 * num3 * num4 * num5) + num1 - (num6 * num7)    
MsgBox ("The size of your room is " & ans)    
    End Sub
```

Thanks Again.

Comment: Apologies, I am using "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications"

Comment: Just use a few formula and data validation in a standard excel file rather than `MsGBox` the user to death.

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for your answer. However, the project I have been set is for a pop up menu. I am not sure if it acceptable for me to have an error be shown in an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: If someone makes an error on num 8 that your code will return to the start again. At the very least you need to give them a chance to re-enter it. There wont be errors in the sheet if you use data validation.

Comment: Are you able to provide the code to do this - or at least start me off?

Comment: see [walls.xlsx](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5d1b99f93ace3ca1&id=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1!122&authkey=!AFwOBIbqXtBpMnE) for an example of data validation

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to validate the input before enter the value to the database, you can use

```
num1 = Val(InputBox("Enter the height of the room"))
if num1>2.4 and num1<6 then
num2 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the first wall"))
num3 = Val(InputBox("Enter the width of the window"))
else
msgbox("It is not a valid input")
end if
```

Comment: frequently showing input boxes will degrade the application quality

Comment: Hello Sujith, I have more information. I will add it onto the original question.

Comment: you can use function for this

Comment: Sujith, is it possible for you to show me how I would do this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: hope that you are satisfied with the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public sub check(n1 as double,n2 as double,a as double,b as double)
If n1 > a And n2 < b Then    
'code comes here
Else    
MsgBox ("It is not a valid input")    
End If   
end sub
```

call the function when you need the condition check; call like this

```
check(num1,num2,2.5,6)' instead of first if
```

Comment: I have encountered a potential problem. As I will be displaying the size at the end, which is currently "ans = (num2 * num3 * num4 * num5) + num1 - (num6 * num7)" If I am correct in thinking this, then this sum would not be possible as we are only using 2 nums.